# How to refer to a specific row in Google Sheets Scripts using a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my script, I need to refer to a specific row by using the number in a variable. For example, if the variable `"rownumber"` is 21, I want to have this code line:

```
var final_row = target_sheet.getRange('21:21');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. Template literals (template string)

```
var final_row = target_sheet.getRange(`${rownumber}:${rownumber}`);
```

2. Addition operator `+`

```
var final_row = target_sheet.getRange(rownumber + ':' + rownumber);
```

3. `Array.prototype.join()`

```
var final_row = target_sheet.getRange([rownumber, rownumber].join(':');
```

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) version of `getRange`:

```
var rownumber = 21;
var final_row = target_sheet.getRange(rownumber,1,1,target_sheet.getMaxColumns());
```

[`getMaxColumns()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns) will give you the full row until the last column of your sheet, starting from the first column.

Alternatively, you can use [`getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) to get from the first column until the last column with content:

```
var rownumber = 21;
var final_row = target_sheet.getRange(rownumber,1,1,target_sheet.getLastColumn());
```